# Run with different home directory

Tags: home

I'm trying to run some programs with a different home directory. I've tried changing `$HOME` when running programs, however several programs I was testing with did not properly use the home directory. Firefox, Chromium, and notepadqq all used the "real" home directory instead of the one I passed as `$HOME`. This is an example of what I tried (with home directory name changed to user):

```
HOME=/home/user/home firefox
```

Running this results in creating a `/home/user/home/.mozilla` with a new profile and settings, but seemingly uses `/home/user/.mozilla` instead.

Comment: I believe Firefox configuration directory location is hardcoded, you cant' change it. AFAIK you can only change your profile directory location. However running  `HOME=/home/user/home firefox` did work on my system.

Comment: Setting `HOME` won't affect applications that read the home directory form the `passwd` database. Your best bet would be to set up another real user.

Comment: @Kusalananda That seems like it could be the best, likely only option. I considered that as an alternative but was hoping for a way to fake the home directory for stubborn applications so all the files would still belong to my main account.

Comment: Well, you could pasnibly use a chroot as an alternative. I'm not writing a proper answer as I don't have an appropriate Linux system to test things on (I'm assuming you're on Linux).

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks, I'll probably just use the multiple accounts method since it seems simpler than setting up a chroot environment.