# How to prevent programs from automatically creating files in home directory?

Tags: files, home

I prefer to have an uncluttered home directory. However, it inevitably gets cluttered up by hidden files and hidden directories which are created automatically by various software: things like `~/.android/`, `~/.audacity-data/`, `~/.dropbox/`, `~/.java/` and hundreds of others.

I understand the purpose is to hold user configurations or other resources. Still, I don't like that the files are created in random locations (some in `~/.local/`, some in `~/.config/`, some just within their own hidden directory in the home folder). In many cases, these files persist even after uninstallation of the software. Even though most files are hidden, the end result is a very cluttered home...

**Is there any way to prevent this from happening?** For example, I imagine a sandbox-type environment where each installed program has a dummy `${HOME}` created with it -- then *all* files automatically created by the program are confined to their own location!

**EDIT**: this is the closest thing I've found that partially answers the question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yy8RoDSdhIQ

Comment: Snaps have their files forced into `~/snap`, FWIW

Comment: You want to only run specific tools that way, right? You don't want this to happen automatically for every program, but just for specific applications you'd deliberately run in a different way?

Comment: @aviro In the general case, I would prefer to have a way to containerize any software in this way. However, I would be okay with installing certain tools (mostly command-line tools like ffmpeg, vim, etc) in the "normal way". Snap is one solution to my problem, but not all software is packaged as a snap (or flatpak). Another is Docker, but I fear it may be excessive and inconvenient to setup a Docker container for every individual software. Surely there is a more elegant way? Maybe some chroot jail or something? I am not sure...

Comment: You could run each program with a different setting of `HOME`?

Comment: @zwets Apparently that doesn't work too well; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/594297

Comment: I'm aware of that, and it gets even weirder with Java programs, which [decouple the meaning of "user home" from the setting of `HOME`](https://askubuntu.com/a/659882/134479). However, as your aim is a setup that goes against the _de facto_ standards, you'll be fighting an uphill battle no matter how.

Comment: It could only work cleanly if every process had separate concepts of `HOME` (your uncluttered paradise) and, say, `STATE` for storing their private user-dependent internal state, but alas this is not the case. The second best solution then was to have it in `$HOME`, but out of sight. Thank god at least we don't call HOME "Documents & Settings", as I've heard some other OS wanted to call it. Sure, that's closer to the truth, but boy would that have been silly.